# R function where output is usable outwith the function

Tags: r, function

So I would like to create a matrix of data in R using a function which I call setupdata. Basically getSymbols get stock data for the given symbols but from a loooong time. I wish to select the latest 60 trading days and therefore has design the following code.

```
getSymbols(c("GOOG","RBS.L","AAPL","FB"),src="yahoo")

setupdata<- function (x){
data2<-x[(dim(x)[1]-59):dim(x)[1],1:6]
print(data2)
}

setupdata(AAPL)
```

My problem is that i would like to be able to use "data2" without needing to call the function anymore after running it once. What am i missing out?

If you want to try it for yourself you might need the quantmod library

```
install.packages("quantmod")
library("quantmod")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return `data2` from the function:

```
setupdata<- function (x){
    data2 <- x[(dim(x)[1]-59):dim(x)[1],1:6]
    return(data2)
}

data2_outside_function = setupdata(AAPL)
```

Comment: The return statement isn't actually needed. You just have to assign the value of `setupdata(AAPL)` to some object, so you can reuse it.